# Arduino - millis() instead of delay() not working

Tags: arduino, delay, arduino-esp8266, milliseconds, blynk

I am an absolute beginner to Arduino, but I am currently working on an IoT project. The goal is to see if temperature and humidity are changing drasticaly over a few minutes.

I am working with an ESP 8266, a DHT11 and the BLYNK App.

I have the following code, where I delay the time between two temperature reads, to calculate the difference between them. I know that delay() is not a good way to work, so I tried to rewrite it with a millis() timer. But it is not working! tempA just stays the same as tempB.

Can someone tell me, what it should look like correctly?

```html
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
    const long interval = 5000;

    void tempChange()
    {
      float tempA;
      float tempB;
      float tempDiff;
      unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

      tempA = dht.readTemperature();

      if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
        previousMillis = currentMillis;
        tempB = dht.readTemperature();
      }

      Serial.print(tempA);
      Serial.print("    ");
      Serial.println(tempB);
    }


    void setup()
    {
      dht.begin();
      timer.setInterval(5000L, tempChange);
      }


    void loop()
    {
      Blynk.run();
      timer.run();
    }
```

If you know any better way, to record a change over time I am open to it. This was just the best (or worst) idea I have come up with.

Thank you!

Comment: this code does not even compile. its `delay` not `dealy` and `currentMillis` is never used

Comment: I am sorry, that was just a typo, that happend, while bringing it in here. I have changed the code to the version where I tried using millis

Comment: 5000 millis is 5 seconds, not a "few minutes."

Comment: I am aware of that

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are reading the same value twice. First you read it and assign it to `tempA` and then you do the same to `tempB`. `tempA` is equal to `tempB` because it's the same reading!

What you want to do is keep track of the previous temperature in a global variable and then, each time you call `tempChange()`, read the value of the sensor and get the difference. Then, change the value of the last temperature to the actual one for the next call.

```cpp
//Create a global variable to keep track of the previous temperature
float previousTemp = dht.readTemperature();

//Call this every "interval" milliseconds
void tempChange()
{
   //Get current temperature and calculate temperature difference
   float currentTemp = dht.readTemperature();
   float tempDiff = currentTemp-previousTemp;

   //Keep track of previous temp
   previousTemp = currentTemp

   //Print results
   Serial.println(previousTemp + " " + currentTemp);
   Serial.println("Change: " + tempDiff);
}
```

Also, you don't need to check the interval with `millis()` when calling the function because you are already calling it every "interval" milliseconds.

Comment: That works perfectly! So simple and yet I spend hours figuring out whats wrong. Thank you very much for your help